# Using Proguard with a library has a @Service bean which should autowire

Tags: spring, obfuscation, proguard, autowired

I have a library Common.License which I am obfuscating with Proguard:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <options>
            <option>-dontoptimize</option>
            <option>-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile</option>
            <option>-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option>
            <option>-keep public class * { public protected *;}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembernames class * {java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String); java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembernames class * {com.common.license.LicenseSessionStore licenseSessionStore; com.common.license.LicenseStore licenseStore;}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembers enum * {public static **[] values(); public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable { static final long serialVersionUID; private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields; private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream); private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream); java.lang.Object writeReplace(); java.lang.Object readResolve();}</option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
        </libs>
        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This library has a Spring bean annotated with @Service:

```
@Service
public class LicenseServiceImpl implements LicenseService {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    LicenseSessionStore licenseSessionStore;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    LicenseStore licenseStore;

...

}
```

I use this library in a web service Company.License where I want the LicenseService to autowire:

```
@Component
public class BackgroundTasks {

    @Autowired
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    @Autowired
    LicenseService licenseService;

...

}
```

So Company.License has a dependency on Common.License.  If I obfuscate Common.License then `licenseService` will not autowire in `BackgroundTasks`.  The only way I could work around this was to define licenseService explicitly as a bean:

```
@Bean(name = "licenseService", autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
public LicenseService getLicenseService() {
    if (licenseService == null) {
        licenseService = new LicenseServiceImpl();
    }
    return licenseService;
}
```

I should not need to explicitly declare this as a bean like this as I have already annotated the class with `@Service` which should be enough to make the autowiring of `licenseService` in `BackgroundTasks` Spring-magically work.  But it doesn't!

What is Proguard specifically doing to make this not work?  Is there anything I can do in the configuration of Proguard to make it more Spring friendly?

Grant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A big thank you to Eric Lafortune for helping point me in the correct direction here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/forums/forum/182456/topic/2547498

Here's the working pom file addition specifying the plug-in and the options required:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <options>
            <option>-dontoptimize</option>
            <option>-keepdirectories</option>
            <option>-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile</option>
            <option>-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option>
            <option>-keep public class * { public protected *;}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembernames class * {java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String); java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembernames class * {com.common.license.LicenseService licenseService; com.common.license.LicenseSessionStore licenseSessionStore;}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembers enum * {public static **[] values(); public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable { static final long serialVersionUID; private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields; private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream); private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream); java.lang.Object writeReplace(); java.lang.Object readResolve();}</option>
            <option>-keep @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Service class *</option>
            <option>-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Controller class *</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembers class * { @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *; }</option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
        </libs>
        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

NOTE!  You need to use ProGuard 4.4, the latest version of ProGuard-Maven-Plugin (2.0.4) uses 4.3 so you need to edit:

```
{M2_HOME}\repository\com\pyx4me\proguard-maven-plugin\2.0.4\proguard-maven-plugin-2.0.4.pom
```

To have the 4.4 dependency (like this):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
  <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
  <version>4.4</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: so the solution was not obfuscating the autowiring annotated classes :/ i can't realy see the benefit from obfuscation , especialy if i'm extensively using spring IOC ( for services , dao etc ..)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to switch to version 4.4 of proguard (which is probably a bit better):

```
<configuration>
  <proguardVersion>4.4</proguardVersion>
  <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
  <options>
  ... 
  </options>    
  <libs>
    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
  </libs>
  <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the -keepdirectories directive helped solve the issue for me.